# Short description of an accomplishment

Tags: phrase-requests

Sometime in the near future, I will achieve the (dubious) distinction of being "the person who has cast the most votes on questions and answers on StackExchange."  I want to add a short statement about this to [my SE profile.](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18597/ward)

But the way I phrased it in the last paragraph seems awkward and somewhat ambiguous.  To be clear, I mean that if you add up all the up/down votes people have cast on all the SE sites they participate in, my total is the highest (approaching 50,000).

Something like "Highest-voting person on StackExchange" seems ambiguous to me - in addition to Q&A votes, there are moderator elections, close votes, deletion votes.  And although "on Stackexchange" is probably ok, I'm not sure that makes it clear that I'm talking about total votes cast across multiple sites.

Perhaps "Highest Q-and-A-voting person on all of StackExchange" would be ok?

I might just wait until I reach 50,000 total votes and say something like "First person on all of StackExchange to cast 50,000 votes across multiple sites."

UPDATE 21 SEP 2012:

By the time I verified today that I'd passed the next-most-active voter, I'd also exceeded 50,000 votes.  So I've included most of the answers in my updated SE profile (see link above), especially:

> I am the most active voter on all of StackExchange. (That is, I have
>   cast the most total question and answer votes across all Stack
>   Exchange sites.)

Comment: Congrats. Quite a distinction.

Comment: Chicago Medalist?

Comment: @StoneyB I think I suggested a "Diebold" badge once...

Comment: `Hi, my name is @Ward and I'm a vote-a-holic` <-? :)

Comment: @Ward  Perhaps the Diebold/Daley award, to keep it non-partisan?

Comment: I think such a badge should allude to or pay homage to Al Capone, who's quoted as saying "vote early, vote often."  [gangland voting] or [Chicago voter] or [vote early, vote often] or [Capone's counsel] or the like.  Maybe that last one, as everyone likes alliteration.

Comment: @HopelessN00b  It [seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote_early_and_vote_often) to predate   Al's rental of the Chicago machine.

Comment: A quote from Knopfler runs through my mind: _"Maybe get a blister on your little finger, maybe get a blister on your thumb."_

Comment: "WORLD LEADER FOR TRIANGLE CLICKING IN STACK EXCHANGE"

Comment: Congrats! I'd rather suggest to link it to a query on data.SE.

Comment: For reference: it's Stack Exchange, not StackExchange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Congratulations in advance for when you become [the most active voter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20most%20active%20voter%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) on Stack Exchange.

If you're worried about losing your title to someone who casts a lot of close/delete/election votes, you could call yourself *the most active **up/down** voter*. But that's probably just the wrong side of the thin line between "committed supporter" and "nerd". I'd settle for the imprecision if I were you.

Comment: I plan to go with "most active voter," possibly with a footnote about it being question/answer votes just in case someone comes along and claims the title of most close or delete votes.

Comment: *Most active* belies a specific time frame in which you cast the most votes, not the person who *has cast* the most votes (of "all time", which is why 'active' can be sorted by week, month, quarter, and all time). *the most active voter of all time* is a little wordy. That's arguably *not* ambiguous, but "(most) prolific" is *not arguably ambiguous*; it's an absolute quantity.

Comment: @Mazura: I assume you meant ***implies*** rather than ***belies*** there, but I disagree anyway. So far as I'm concerned, the default "time-frame" scope for ***most active*** and ***most prolific*** is the same (***all***). To the extent that there could be a difference between the two words in the context of a Q&A site like ELU, all I see is that ***most active*** implies logging on and/or contributing more ***often*** where ***most prolific*** implies posting a greater ***volume*** of material (maybe a smaller number of longer posts, and/or less "total visits").

Answer (score 4):

What about "I have cast the most total votes across all Stack Exchange sites."?

Comment: [Removed code quotes: code quotes have a special purpose]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

"First person to cast 50,000 votes on the StackExchange network."

(Or "family of sites" or similar, if you don't like "network.")

Answer (score 1):

You might try "I am credited for being the person who has cast the most votes on questions and answers on StackExchange."

Answer (score 1):

I have the dubious distinction of collecting 50k in votes on stackexchange sites of interest.

Answer (score 1):

**(the most) *prolific***

> Adjective (*comparative* more prolific, *superlative* most prolific)
>
> 1. Fertile, producing offspring or fruit in abundance "” applied to plants producing fruit, animals producing young, etc.
> 2. Similarly **producing results or works in abundance**
>
> Origin
>
> 1640-1650: from French *prolifique*, from Latin *proles* (“offspring") and *facere* (“to make").
>
> – [yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/prolific)

*"the most prolific"*, ~9M hits verbatim.